# Why is this syntax a valid C# Interface implementation?

Tags: c#

I am getting up to speed on C# and came across this syntax for declaring an interface implementation which I don't understand:

```
namespace Mapbox.Examples.LocationProvider
{

    public class PositionWithLocationProvider : MonoBehaviour
    {

    ILocationProvider _locationProvider;
    public ILocationProvider LocationProvider
    {
        private get
        {
            if (_locationProvider == null)
            {
                _locationProvider = _useTransformLocationProvider ?
                    LocationProviderFactory.Instance.TransformLocationProvider : LocationProviderFactory.Instance.DefaultLocationProvider;
            }

            return _locationProvider;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_locationProvider != null)
            {
                _locationProvider.OnLocationUpdated -= LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated;

            }
            _locationProvider = value;
            _locationProvider.OnLocationUpdated += LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated;
        }
    }

        Vector3 _targetPosition;

        void LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated(object sender, LocationUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
                _targetPosition = doStuff();
        }


    void Start()
    {
        LocationProvider.OnLocationUpdated += LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated;
        _map.OnInitialized += () => _isInitialized = true;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (LocationProvider != null)
        {
            LocationProvider.OnLocationUpdated -= LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated;
        }
    }


    }
}
```

The line `public ILocationProvider LocationProvider` is a mystery to me. No class or struct implements the interface. Can someone please clarify for me?

### UPDATE 0

I've added the entire `ILocationProvider` which shows the assignment `_locationProvider = value;`

### UPDATE 1

For completeness I added the Start() and OnDestroy() methods. The use of the upper case - `LocationProvider` - somehow refers to the property `_locationProvider`? Hummm. It just looks a bit odd.

Comment: That's just creating a property of type `ILocationProvider` on this class.  Just like any other property.  (With a private `get`, which is kind of rare and personally I think a little weird, but not unheard of.)

Comment: Isn't it a bug that in the setter, _locationProvider isn't actually set to `value` ?

Comment: @Fildor: Good question.  This property is certainly *weird* to me, and I'd want to have a conversation with anybody on my team who writes something like this.  Though we don't really know the context of this code or what it's supposed to do.  The question is about the syntax, and the syntax is perfectly valid.

Comment: @David I agree. I just wanted to have it mentioned. It's definitely a weird implementation of a setter. I suspect it should go on to set the field and register the EventHandler on the updated LocationProvider instance.

Comment: After Update: Yes, now it's clear. That makes sense now.

Comment: So, is the down voting of perfectly reasonable questions a Stackoverflow thing?

Comment: It's not only questions. Sometimes you will also see correct, accepted, working, nicely written answers getting downvoted for no obvious reason.

Comment: @dugla: I wouldn't take the downvotes personally.  (I didn't vote either way, if that matters.)  The question is a little strange, to be honest.  The original code showed a *very* odd property implementation, though the updated code is much less odd.  But the question itself doesn't necessarily line up with the code being shown.  You're asking about an interface implementation, but just showing a property.  Some users may find that unclear.  Perhaps you're just getting terminology mixed up while learning C#?  This is okay, even though some users may find it unclear.

Comment: "The use of the upper case - LocationProvider - somehow refers to the property _locationProvider" - not automatically. It is a common practice or convention to use "_name" for private fields and "PropertyName" for (public) properties. To make sure it is clear that the two relate, you'd make the two names correlate like `private string _myName;` and Property `public string MyName ...`. Of course *you* have to make sure you are using "_myName" field in the getter/setter impls of the Property.

Comment: @David you are a lone voice of sanity. I am indeed getting up to speed on C# from too many other languages to count. I'll get there. Cheers.

Comment: @Fildor. Wow. The verbosity and elaborate syntax of C# coming from JS and Swift is a real shocker. Thanks.

Comment: @dulga Well, every language has its "specialties". I am not too familiar with JS and don't know anything about Swift, but coming from Java (well, actually switch back and forth between C# and Java), I can tell you I *love* Properties in C#. You'll have a better time learning it if you "empty the cup" to cite Bruce Lee. That's what I learned from switching from Java to C# and back. It will only block your mind if you have that "whoa but in XYZ, I could just do yadda yadda" attitude. If you manage to lose that, you'll start to see the beauties of the "new" language.

Comment: @Fildor. Yah, I hear you. I like that - empty the cup. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocationProvider` is not an interface implementation, but a property, that can take an `ILocationProvider`. Think of it as a more beautiful version of getter/setter methods.

If would be (pretty much) equivialent to

```
public ILocationProvider GetLocationProvider()
{
  return _locationProvider
}

public void SetLocationProvider(ILocationProvider locationProvider)
{
  if(_locationProvider != null)
  {
    // unsubscribe events
  }

  _locationProvider = locationProvider;
  // subscribe events
}
```

(I've been so bold and fixed the logic of the setter a bit.)

Used like this it's a flavour of dependency injection called *setter injection*. The dependency (`ILocationProvider` implementation) is not created by `PositionWithLocationProvider`, but injected via a property.

Comment: `_locationProvider = locationProvider;` That part is missing in the original snippet, though.

Comment: @Fildor In the property it would be `_locationProvider = value;`, but, yeah.

Comment: Yes it would have to be `=value;` - considered that detail trivial.

Comment: I suspect, it has been left out for brevity by OP. I also suspect it goes on to register the Event on the injected instance.

Comment: @Fildor. Correct.